# ngbTooltip in Angular not in the center of the item

Tags: html, css, ng-bootstrap

Does anyone know why the tooltip is not at the center(center-top) of the item?

here is the picture... as you can see its a little bit more on the right of the top center

[item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eU5J2.jpg)

and the same is on the other items.. here it will be easier to see

[item 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzJ7b.jpg)

here is my html code:

```
<button class="btn btn-icon coverage-item "
        type="button"
        placement="top"
        ngbTooltip="Incendio">
  <img src="/assets/img/coverages/icon_thunderbolt.svg"/>
</button>
```

and this is the scss code:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss";
@import "../../scss/variables";

.coverage-item {
  background: $white;
  border: 1.5px solid $brand-primary;
  color: $gray-light;
  height: 3.5rem;
  width: 3.5rem;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 0rem 0rem;
}

.coverage-item__new {
  background: $white;
  border: 1.5px dashed $gray-lighter;
  color: $gray-light;
  height: 3.5rem;
  width: 3.5rem;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 0rem 0rem;
```

Comment: What's the CSS for the tooltips? That's kind of essential to this question..

Comment: I don't think anyone can guess without a reproduce scenario (and I'm saying this as one of ng-bootstrap authors). Can you try to reproduce it in a plunker? You can start with this one: http://plnkr.co/edit/criNVo28tU3rm4mZjMCk?p=preview

Comment: @Tijmen it's a bootsrap default css if it's that what you did mean.

ahhh yeap plnkr, forgot about it.. thanks I will try to reproduce it and I will come back.

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource here it is http://plnkr.co/edit/vIKCOs?p=info
it just doesn't show nothing because I don't know how to get imported those file in the theme.scss file that I created. Comment the styleURL and it will work but it won't show the bug. I think the problem is in the code in theme.scss

Comment: It could well be in the other CSS file. Did you try a [CSS validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)?

Comment: @Tijmen I really haven't.. but I just resolved the problem :) 
Just added this code to my scss file

  .tooltip {
    margin-left: -2px;
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

I just added this code to my scss file and it's working.

```
app-coverage-item {
  .tooltip {
    margin-left: -2px;
  }
}
```